# Maximum modulus principle for harmonic functions using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Let $D$ be a star domain and $u: D \to \mathbb{R}$ harmonic. Assume there exists a $\zeta \in D$ s.t. $u(z) \leq u(\zeta)\; \forall z \in D$. Show that $u$ is constant.

Harmonic functions on star domains always have harmonic conjugates. So there exists a harmonic $v:D\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f = u+iv$ is holomorphic on $D$. Now because $u(z) \leq u(\zeta)$ we have $\text{Re}(g) \geq 0$ where $g(z) := f(\zeta) - f(z)$. Now I'd like to show that $\text{Re}(g) > 0$ so that there exists a holomorphic $h:D\to \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $g(z) = \exp(h(z))$. Am I going the wrong direction or is there an easier way to show this?

Comment: So you know the maximum modulus principle for holomorphic functions and want to use that to prove the statement about harmonic functions?

Comment: Yes exactly. To add to tthat, the hint of the exercise literally states 'use the exponential function' and we had a proposition that says for holomorphic functions on domains with no zeros we can write $f = \exp(h)$ with holomorphic $h$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential function can be used, but not as you tried but by considering the function $h(z) = e^{f(z)}$. $h$ is holomorphic in $D$, and
$$
 |h(z)| = e^{\operatorname{Re}f(z)} = e^{u(z)} \le e^{u(\xi)} \, ,
$$
with equality for $z = \xi$. The maximum modules principle for holomorphic functions implies that $h$ is constant. It follows that $f$, and consequently $u$, are constant.

Comment: Why is $h(z)$ holomorphic in $D$? We don't know that $f(z)$ has no zeros on $D$. What am I missing?

Comment: $h$ is simply a composition of holomorphic functions.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much!

Comment: @Shuster ??? Zeroes of $f$ have nothing to do with this; we;re not looking for a _logarithm_ of $f$. If $h(z)=e^0$ then $h$ is holomorphic